# Problem with React Router And Apollo GraphQL Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am having a bit of a challenge with Apollo Client and React Router in my Vite react app. When the page first initially loads everything is perfectly the data is also obtain with no errors. The problems begins when I try to access a different route and returns back to the homepage, the Apollo Client fetches data and returns null data.

screenshot

[image]

[Gihub Link](https://github.com/DevHumbleChris/montflix-rebirth)

[Website Link](http://montflix-rebirth.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this I just figured it out u should include (data &&)

code:

```
{data && (
          <>
            {data.category.products.map(item=>(
                <AllCard    
                    image={item.gallery} 
                    name={item.name}
                 />
                 ))}
           </>)
}
```